# How do i center these nav items?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matty104/928p7/) and you can see the nav items are align to the left. Is there a way to center these items regardless of nav items, because I will have one more nav item when the user logs in...any ideas

Here is my html

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="has-sub "><a href="#"><span>Products</span></a>
     <ul>
        <li class="has-sub "><a href="#"><span>Product 1</span></a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub "><a href="#"><span>Product 2</span></a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make your and `li` are `display:block` (perhaps you want to give them same widths), you got the right idea with `relative` positioning, just add the following properties:

```
#cssmenu ul {
    left: 50%;
}
#cssmenu ul li{
    right: 50%;
}
```

If not, make your `li` simply `display:inline` removing all the other stuff and simply doing:

```
#cssmenu { text-align: center; }
#cssmenu ul { list-style: none; }
#cssmenu ul li { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: -50%;  <--- here
}
```

seems to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to your main `ul`:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul class="menu">
    ...
```

Then in css:

```
ul.menu {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
var $menu = $('ul.menu');
$menu.css('margin-left', -$menu.outerWidth() / 2 +'px' );​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/4TcsP/1/

Answer (score 0):

Make menu display as inline-block, and set #cssmenu text-align: center.

```
#cssmenu > ul {
  display: inline-block
}
#cssmenu {
  text-align: center;
}
```

PS: It's better to give your menu container a class name, as well as the menu items.